# Logical regression question: one variable, two estimates. How to understand and explain the result?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, model

I want to know the relationship between educational background (x) and certain action (y)

In my data, education has three types of factors: 0 = low, 1 = middle, and 2 = high. Certain action has two types of factors: 0 = no certain action, 1 = do certain action

Now, my code (in R) is:

```
res <- glm(Y ~ education, na.action = na.omit,  data = data, family = 'binomial')
summary(res)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.34801    0.03166 -74.164  < 2e-16 ***
education1   0.24036    0.04572   5.257 1.46e-07 ***
education2   0.44785    0.03886  11.526  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 27548  on 39456  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 27409  on 39454  degrees of freedom
  (1731 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 27415
```

Why the result contains two coefficients of education?

If I write the model: y = -2.35 + 0.24*edu1 + 0.45*edu2, what are the meanings of edu1 and edu2?

How can I evaluate the significance of my model? The model is so strange.

Comment: Did you code the education variable as a factor?

Comment: Yes, I use the as.factor() to transform them to factor variables

Comment: Do you understand how ANOVA works as a linear regression and what happens with the intercept?

Comment: what do you imply from two estimates ? You have mentioned the outcome 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result shows only two coefficients for education because glm converts factors (e.g., your education variable) into indicator variables for each level. Since having all theee indicators would be redundant (because if you know the education is not medium or high, it must be low) you only see two, with the third being implicit.

When you write  y = -2.35 + 0.24edu1 + 0.45edu2, the variable y is actually the log-odds of "do cerain action." To convert it to a probability simply compute $p=\frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$. This is the inverse logit function i.e. the logistic function. Edu1 and Edu2 are indicator variables which will be eithier 0 or 1 depending on the education level of an observation. If both are 0, then the education level is "low" i.e. edu0.

You can evaluate the significance of the coefficients by looking at the Pr(>=|z|) column of the summary table. Values with one or more * are significant at at least the 0.05 level.

To gain more intuition for your results, consider using the "predict" function to see what your model would predict given new data. You can see how it reacts to the various education levels as well as any additional predictors you may consider in the future.

Comment: Thank you, David. I've considered the possibility of dummy variables. But I don't know the meaning of two coefficients. I  mean maybe "edu1  = 1" means it is low education, but it also may mean it is high education.

Comment: Ah see. I thought from you post that they were coded as 0, 1, and 2 for low, middle, and high respectively. The glm function will use the first factor as the baseline/implicit, so that made sense given your encoding i.e. 0 is implicit. If my reading of your post was incorrect however, and the factor names are different, let me know and I can attempt to rediagnose the issue.

Comment: Wow, now I understand how to explain this result. Thank you very much!